# Pass data and calculate between two components

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to know what is the most efficient and neat way when I pass data from one to another component. The flow is:

I have two components inside one home page in angular as:

```
   <component-1 (addItem)="addItem($event)"></component-1>
   <component-2 [items]="item"></component-2>
```

In my home component I just do:

```
addItem (item: any) {
    this.items.push(item);
}
```

and I pass the items as input to the second component. But, in the same time I need to calculate and show the total items number (items.lenght) inside my second component (let totalItems = this.items.lenght; )

I have tried with ngOnChanges() it does not work, ngDoCheck() works but I am not sure how efficient and performance wise good it is. As I have seen that this life-cycle is executed very often.

Basically **every time when [items] input is changed i need to calculate the total number** inside the component-2.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the length as an *@Input*

Template

```
<component-1 (addItem)="addItem($event)"></component-1>
<component-2 [items]="item" [total]="items.length"></component-2>
```

Component 2

```
@Input() total: number;
```

Comment: Yes I know about this, and that I can calculate the length in my main component and than pass it, but I still wanted to know how to calculate inside the component itself once the input or data has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't update automatically because the reference to `this.items` isn't changed when you push new items using the `push` method. Instead you could try to change the reference using the [de-structuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Try the following

```js
addItem (item: any) {
  this.items = [...this.items, item];
}
```

Now there wouldn't be a need for `ngOnChanges()` or `ngDoCheck()` in 'component-2'.